# How to pass a pair of images first through a conv net and then through a recurrent net in Keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I would like to compare two images with both a convolutional and a recurrent network. First I want to pass my first image through some VGG-like stack, then feed it into a first RNN input. Then the second image should pass THE SAME VGG and after that go into a second input of the RNN.

How do I implement this topology with Keras?

The recurrent network should remember the first image while processing the second.

**UPDATE**

Suppose I have two inputs:

```
input1 = layers.Input(...)
input2 = layers.Input(...)
```

Currently I have two VGG branches

```
x1 = vgg_stack(...)(x1)
x2 = vgg_stack(...)(x2)

x = layers.concatenate([x1, x2])

x = final_MLP(...)(x)
```

How would I replace it with signle `vgg_stack` applied to both inputs, and then these results are passed to `RNN`?

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use the TimeDistributed wrapper. You can find [the doc here](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/)

It basically takes the first dimension after the batch as a 'temporal dimension' and it applies the layer (or model?) that you give as an argument to every temporal step. So use it like this :

```
from keras.layers import TimeDistributed

input_layer = Input((num_of_images, image_dims...))
# m_cnn is your VGG like model, taking one image as input.
layer1 = TimeDistributed(m_cnn)(input_layer)
layer2 = YourRNNLayer(...)(layer1)
```

I hope this makes sense to you :)

Comment: I don't understand sorry. I have 2 inputs: `input1` and `input2`. What next?

Comment: I am unable to use `m_cnn` if it is not a `Layer`